# Is it possible to modify the source of an iframe from a java rest api call?

Tags: javascript, java, html, iframe

I have a dropwizard based application that starts a web page with an iframe.

`<iframe id="someId" name="someName"></iframe>`

Simple so far. Everytime I navigate to my url there's an iframe which does nothing. I want to dynamically set a src attribute for this iframe through a rest API call from the backend. Basically this allows me to use some java code to return html that reads the id of this iframe and sets a src.

```
    private String html = "<html>\n"
    + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
    + "function myFunction () {\n"
    + "var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById"
    + "(\"someId\");\n"
    + "    iframe.src = \"https://localhost:9999/api/someApi\"\n"
    + "}\n"
    + "window.onload = setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);\n"
    + "</script>\n"
    + "</html>";

@GET
@Path("/invokeFrame")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response invokeFrame()
{
    return Response.ok(html).build();
}
```

When I make this API call, it returns html that finds the iframe and sets a src. But this doesn't work because when the API is called, it redirects me to a blank page (away from my webpage which contains the iframe), so `window.parent.document.getElementById` does not read the iframe. Instead it's `null`. Is there a quick/dirty way to prevent redirection and stay on my page so that the iframe src can be changed?